# Wrong value of $(window).height() and element width onload and on document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to center the content of my page using jQuery. Everything works perfectly after resize, however it doesn't work at all using both $(window).load and $(document).ready

Here is my code:

```
    <script>
        $(window).load(function() {
        if ($('.container-fix').outerWidth() > 768) {
            var a = ($(window).width() - $('.container-fix').outerWidth()) / 2;
                alert($('.container-fix').outerHeight());
                alert($(window).height());
                $('.container-fix').css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    left: ($(window).width() - $('.container-fix').outerWidth()) / 2,
                    top: ($(window).height() - $('.container-fix').outerHeight()) / 2
                });
            } else {
                $('.container-fix').removeAttr('style');
            }
            $('.dziekujemy-bg').css({
                height: $('iframe').outerHeight() + 6
            })
    });
    </script>
    <script>
    function resizeWidth() {
        var existingWidth = $(document).data('resize-width');
        var newWidth = $(document).width();
        if (existingWidth != newWidth) {
            if ($('.container-fix').outerWidth() > 768) {
                $('.container-fix').css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    left: ($(window).width() - $('.container-fix').outerWidth()) / 2,
                    top: ($(window).height() - $('.container-fix').outerHeight()) / 2
                });
            } else {
                $('.container-fix').removeAttr('style');
            }
            $('.dziekujemy-bg').css({
                height: $('iframe').outerHeight() + 6
            })
            $(document).data('resize-width', newWidth);
        };
    };

    $(window).resize(resizeWidth);
    </script>
```

The second script works perfectly, first one I have created only to try to execute the code on initial page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit - Answer changed 8/27/2015

Make your container div `display:inline-block` at some point before it is made opaque.  So if you're not going to fade in, set its style or class to force `inline-block`

```
<div id="container" class="container-fix" style="display:inline-block;">
```

Alternatively, hide the div by default using `display:none`, and use something like [`jQuery.fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) at the end of your document's ready, or window's load event handler.

```
<div id="container" class="container-fix" style="display:none;">
```

...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
    $('.container-fix').fadeIn(500);
});
```

### Regarding previous answer

I had answered this with a block of code that worked, but not for the reason I indicated.  I stated that a missing semicolon was to blame.  Thank you to squint for pointing out my mistake.

> That's not an error in JS. There's no reason adding a semicolon would make the code work. –  squint

I agree that it is not a js error to omit semicolons at the end of statements.  That being said I was still convinced that this was a situation where this was not a syntax error, but lead to a parse error down the road due to the context that js ended up being interpreted in.  I spent some time convincing myself that wasn't the issue, and now completely agree with you squint.  I'm actually kind of embarrassed that I threw this out there as an answer and allowed it to become accepted.

So why was my sample working as expected?

Later it occurred to me that I actually modified the code in a non-insignificant way when I added the `$().fadeIn()`.  I believe what is happening is you have a block level element with a default CSS `display` value of `block`.  By using `$('.container-fix').fadeIn()` the styling on the selected element is changing from the default `block` to `inline-block`.  I had explicitly specified `style=display:none` in my example, overriding the default value of `block`.  So you didn't actually see the div until its display was changed from `none` to `inline-block`.

---

### Initial (wrong) answer that was already marked accepted

I'm leaving this here for reference only

Fix the js errors first and what you have will work.  Semi-colons missing after this block...

```
$('.dziekujemy-bg').css({
    height: $('iframe').outerHeight() + 6
}) // <--- add semi-colon
```

Here's a stripped down version, taken from the source of the link you posted, with a little transition added so you don't see the div jump on page load after center is calculated.

```
<!doctype html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-testimonials.css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/modernizr.min.js"></script>
  <script defer="" src="http://nasfactor.com/themes/dotsquare/html/html/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
  <title>Do zobaczenia w niedzielę 30.08.2015 o 17:00</title>
  <!-- Tutaj tytuł strony -->
  <!-- Facebook Conversion Code for Rejestracja -->
  <img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?ev=6025672695760&amp;cd[value]=0.01&amp;cd[currency]=THB&amp;noscript=1" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id='divLoading'>Loading...</div>

  <div id="container" class="container-fix" style="display:none;">
    <article class="span7">
      <section>
        <div class="embed-container embed-frame">
          <iframe src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/bWA6h-F-jho' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
      </section>
    </article>
    <aside class="span5 col">
      <div class="dziekujemy-bg">
        <div class="position-fix">
          <p>Do zobaczenia na webinarze! Ustaw sobie przypomnienie w telefonie na niedzielę o 16:00 (webinar startuje o 17:00)!</p>
          <p>Chcę przygotować ten webinar specjalnie dla Ciebie - dlatego proszę wypełnij krótką ankietę - a poruszę na webinarze sprawy ważne dla Ciebie:</p>
          <p><a href="#">ANKIETA - KLIKNIJ</a>
          </p>
          <p style="margin-bottom:0">Dziękuję bardzo!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </aside>
  </div>


  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      if ($('.container-fix').outerWidth() > 768) {
        var a = ($(window).width() - $('.container-fix').outerWidth()) / 2;
        // alert($('.container-fix').outerHeight());
        // alert($(window).height());
        $('.container-fix').css({
          position: 'absolute',
          left: ($(window).width() - $('.container-fix').outerWidth()) / 2,
          top: ($(window).height() - $('.container-fix').outerHeight()) / 2
        });
      } else {
        $('.container-fix').removeAttr('style');
      }
      $('.dziekujemy-bg').css({
        height: $('iframe').outerHeight() + 6
      });
      $('div#container').fadeIn(500);
      $('div#divLoading').fadeOut(500);
    });
  </script>
  <script>
    function resizeWidth() {
      var existingWidth = $(document).data('resize-width');
      var newWidth = $(document).width();
      if ((existingWidth != newWidth) || $(document).ready) {
        if ($('.container-fix').outerWidth() > 768) {
          $('.container-fix').css({
            position: 'absolute',
            left: ($(window).width() - $('.container-fix').outerWidth()) / 2,
            top: ($(window).height() - $('.container-fix').outerHeight()) / 2
          });
        } else {
          $('.container-fix').removeAttr('style');
        }
        $('.dziekujemy-bg').css({
          height: $('iframe').outerHeight() + 6
        });
        $(document).data('resize-width', newWidth);
      };
    };

    $(window).resize(resizeWidth);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's not an error in JS. There's no reason adding a semicolon would make the code work.